# Site Settings permissions missing in omni-box shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

Previously when you click the icon on the far left of the omni-box the drop-down would give your quick access to set permission for the current site.  Those are now gone. If you click on site sittings it takes you to where you can set global permissions. Is there a setting to get this back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of complaints regarding this, but as usual, Google knows what's best for you:

[Website permissions are missing from the menu](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=483899)

[Improve the display of permissions in the Origin Info Bubble](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444244) (Note the word 'improve'.)

Unless I missed it I don't see a setting anywhere to revert this change.

Comment: I have a new replacement feature I'm working on. Lets remove the old one now. New one will ship in three months.